# Extracting multiple multidimensional coordinates (lat/lon) from NETCDF files within shapefile polygons using xarray

Tags: arrays, dataframe, multidimensional-array, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file (CRS Lambert Conformal) with temperature data from weather stations at certains lon/lat (for several time steps) and shapefiles(CRS EPSG:4326) for several regions.
I want to be able to create a new array containing only the temperature data for this specific region (shapefile) and be able to grab the temperature at certain points within this region.

The array looks like this

```
xarray.Dataset

    Dimensions:           X: 720        Y: 938        time: 744
    Coordinates:
        X                 (X) int32 3670500 3671500 ... 4388500 4389500
        Y                 (Y) int32 2242500 2243500 ... 3178500 3179500
        lon               (Y, X) float64 5.545 5.559 5.572 ... 16.33 16.35
        lat               (Y, X) float64 46.72 46.72 46.72 ... 55.37 55.37
        time              (time) datetime64[ns] 2012-12-01 ... 2012-12-31T23:00:00
    Data variables:
        Lambert_Conformal () |S1 b''
        datum             (time) float64 ...
        temperature       (time, Y, X) float32 ...
```

and the shapefiles like this

```
81    POLYGON ((11.85420 47.94340, 11.84867 47.94343...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

I have tried to figure this out by looking among others into similiar questions like

[assign-coordinates-as-dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880746/xarray-missingspatialdimensionerror-assign-coordinates-as-dimensions)

and
[assign-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770276/assign-new-coordinates-to-a-variable-using-xarray?rq=1)

as well as
[Working with multidimensional coords](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html)

But I just cant't work out a solution for this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shapely.vectorized.contains` to quickly identify which points are contained within a shapely geometry. You do need to align the crs of the points and geometries - it looks from your previews like both your shapefile and your lat/lon coordinates are in lat/lon, and I’ll assume they’re in the same crs:

```py
in_shape = shapely.vectorized.contains(
    shape, # a single shapely geometry, e.g. gdf.geometry.item()
    ds.lon,
    ds.lat,
)
```

This returns a Boolean ndarray - you could convert back to xarray and mask your data like this:

```py
mask = xr.DataArray(in_shape, dims=ds.lon.dims, coords=ds.lon.coords)
masked = ds.where(mask)
```